# Why might a development version of my Xamarin.Forms app not install on a physical Android test device after incrementing the target API?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, apk, visual-studio-app-center

I have an established Xamarin.Forms app which builds fine through the Microsoft App Center and installs on my own physical Android device after distribution as an APK for testing purposes.

A second user can no longer install the distributed version on their own Android device. They receive a generic "You can't install the app on your device" toast message when trying to install from the distributed APK.

This problem has only started since targeting API 30+ (tried on 30 and 31, it's fine on 29).

Strangely, when I publish the app and distribute through the Play Store, the app works fine on both test devices - so there is some issue on this one device that only occurs when installing from APK (and the API is targetting > 29).

I'm not sure what to investigate next, any pointers or insight would be much appreciated :-D

Comment: Have you looked at the logs on the device?

Comment: I haven't as of yet (and actually, this would be the first time i've needed to do that) - any pointers on the most user-friendly way to retrieve them? (I don't have physical access to the device)

Comment: Do you know on what device this problem appears on? Does this problem only occur on fixed models of devices?

Comment: Hi there - this is the only device the issue occurs on so far - but we only have two physical test devices (our own phones).

I have taken this info from the header of the log file -

Build: RPAS31.Q2-59-17-4-3-8
Build fingerprint: 'motorola/odessa_retaile/odessa:11/RPAS31.Q2-59-17-4-3-8/fdb23c:user/release-keys'


. Nothing immediately obvious relating to error/warnings about our app.

Comment: Phone is a Moto g(9) plus. With Android 11